# javascript_include_tag Rails 4 generating "/javascripts/" instead of "/assets" in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 4 application with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

in the head. In development, the following HTML is rendered, and modernizr is loaded:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1"></script>
```

In production, the followign HTML is rendered, and modernizr is *not* loaded (404 not found):

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/javascripts/modernizr.js"></script>
```

In production, `/assets/modernizr.js` is found and browsable.

The [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag) says that the `javascript_include_tag` should generate

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1"></script>
```

In production, my `stylesheet_link_tag`s are fine, linking to the `/assets/` directory.

Why is the `javascript_include_tag` linking to `/javascripts` instead of `/assets` in production, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem, but none of the answers here help.

Comment: in production, you should have a fingerprinted asset-url like `/assets/light-0cd9377b97b67182b68c8023bd6c2fbe.css`

Comment: Is this clean Rails 4 app or an upgrade from earlier Rails version?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the usage statements for AssetUrlHelper indicates it will produce /javascripts/ urls
like what you are seeing:

#   asset_path "application", type: :javascript     # => /javascripts/application.js

(from asset_url_helper.rb line 117 - [[1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/863c488bb05de3b38a81fa37349977adc0db59e3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L117)])

This code looks like it can only be reached if the precompiled asset is missing
so it would appear that your asset compilation is not working (my deployments usually
fail when that happens, so maybe yours isn't even firing).

The same asset_url_helper.rb calls the /javascripts/ part 'extname' and
uses the following map to know how to generate the name:

```
 # Maps asset types to public directory.
  ASSET_PUBLIC_DIRECTORIES = {
    audio:      '/audios',
    font:       '/fonts',
    image:      '/images',
    javascript: '/javascripts',
    stylesheet: '/stylesheets',
    video:      '/videos'
  }
```

A new Rails 4 app has this in the config/environments/production.rb

```
  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
```

which seems to match the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: thank you! Some js/css file not precompiled,cause it can't associated with application.js/css file,so rails 4 assets precompile can't find those files. You can add file to precompile file list as this `#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += [ Proc.new {|path| File.basename(path) =~ /^[^_].*\.\w+$/} ]`

Comment: Rails seems to have some very bad defaults for the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 12):

By default, Rails only precompiles `application.js`, `application.css` and any images it finds in the assets path. Therefore, in production mordernizr will not get precompiled and thus the javascript helpers will not be able to find the file.

In order to fix the issue, you can add modernizr to the precompile list by modifying the following config in `production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += ['modernizr.js']
```

For more information see [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: This answer is correct. In prod, if `javascript_include_tag` cannot find the precompiled javascript asset in the searching path (which is `./public/assets/ ` I think), it will generate `src` starting with `/javascripts/` (Rails thinks you will put that assets in `./public/javascripts/`). In dev, `config.assets.compile` is set to `true`, so if `javascript_include_tag` cannot find the assets in `./public/assets`, rails will compile the assets, then it will find it. In production, `config.assets.compile` is `false`. So use `config.assets.precompile` to make sure your assets are precompiled.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to precompile your assets in production by running this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The Rails Guide on the asset pipeline can give you more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: But this only compiles the assets into the `public/assets/` folder - it doesn't explain why the path is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: Did you change the path in your `production.rb`? It would look like `config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path

Comment: No, I didn't. All my assets in `vendor/` get compiled correctly into `/assets` and the paths are correct. It's just javascripts in `/app/assets` for some reason have the wrong path generated by `javascript_include_tag`. And yes, I added them to `precompile`. Really strange behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

I have a new application using Rails 4 deployed on Heroku with :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

my javascript application.(fingerprint).js called from the src: assets/application.js

i think your problem come from something into your production.rb who define assets from another location.

So maybe you can add Moderniz.js to

> config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']

in config/production.rb

Or simply require modernizr script into your application.js

> //= require mordernizr

and remove the modernizr script call into your layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Can you check from where your application.js is served into your production environment ?

Answer (score -1):

It may be because this file needs to be in /vendor/assets/javascript instead of /app/assets/javascript. The Vendor folder is for javascript libraries, and the App folder is for your code.

A better solution than adding a tag to your layout would be adding a script reference to your application.js and let the sass compiler compress and attach it to your main javascript file.

If you don't get a definitive answer, check out:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: The files in both `/vendor/assets/javascript/` and `/app/assets/javascript/` folders get compiled into the `public/assets/` folder, and the generated `manifest.json` file describes the logical paths to find the fingerprinted files. However, for this to work, the path generated by `javascript_include_tag` still needs to point to `assets/`.