# JQuery and JQuery ujs tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, liquid

I need to get access to Jquery and Jquery-ujs through the liquid template language. To do this i use `javascript_include_tag("jquery")` to get the file to work in production.

The problem is that javascript_include_tag is giving me the wrong links:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js"></script>
```

What i need is something similar to this in development:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js"></script>
```

I believe the problem is related to how i call the `javascript_include_tag`.

Comment: Why are you including these in your view, and not the manifest of your `application.js` file - any particular reason?

Comment: Because i need these file in my Liquid theme language. So I'm including them in a Liquid method. I already use them on the back end throught applicaiton.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript\_include\_tag Rails 4 generating "/javascripts/" instead of "/assets" in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622858/javascript-include-tag-rails-4-generating-javascripts-instead-of-assets-i)